# how to print a structured document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, flowdocument, printdocument

i'm a student that learning coding and i'm very new in asp.net. i'm learning on how to print a document that able to design by coding. i tried with C# WPF by using FlowDocument but i think ASP.net does not have flowDocument right? so what is the alternative way that able to do similar things in asp.net. I'm trying to print document that contain image and text as picture attached below. Thank you so much in advance =D
 [example picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXUvP.png)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net and any web platform, *you don't print anything at all*. The **browser** does. This is a security feature (meaning you won't be able to easily bypass it) intended to prevent rogue or compromised web sites from littering your printer with the kind of junk corporate fax machines used to collect.

All you do is render a page to the browser that has the content you want, and the user will print via the browser's print options.

Comment: Thanks for your information Joel. I think i manage to do it by compiling the information that i wanted and generate it as PDF with adding
 _ var jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
 writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);_

Once the PDF created, open the PDF file and it will prompt the user to print it. =D